# Highcharts flag series disappearing when zooming out

Tags: typescript, highcharts

When I zoom out on my Highcharts Highstock chart with a flag series the flags disappear.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add "allowOverlapX: true " to the series config. So now my config for the flag series is:

```
const series = {
  type : 'flags',
  id: seriesId,
  data : flagDatas,
  name: label,
  onSeries : ticker,  // Id of which series it should be placed on. If not defined
  // the flag series will be put on the X axis
  shape : 'flag',  // Defines the shape of the flags.
  grouping: false,
  allowOverlapX: true
};
```

Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.flags.allowOverlapX